# Check if fontseries exists

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I want to check if the actual font used has a special fontseries installed, for example:

```
%check for semibold
\ifx\fontseries{sb} % doesnt work
    \def\textsb#1{\fontseries{sb}\selectfont #1}
\else
    \let\textsb\textbf
\fi
```

I would appreciate an answer without use of extra package.

Comment: You might look at the code of `nfssext` or `nfssext-cfr` to see how the 'Font Installation' manual does this. However, that solution, unlike egreg's depends on fonts using Karl Berry names.

Comment: My font and I think most fonts using Karl Berry names so also the answer from Will is pretty good and works fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertine} % Libertine has sb

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\sbseries}{%
  \@tempswafalse
  \sbox\z@{%
    % Disable warnings for missing fonts
    \let\@font@warning\@gobble
    % Save the current value of \@defaultsubs
    \let\@tempsubs\@defaultsubs
    % try sb
    \fontseries{sb}\selectfont
    % the value of \@defaultsubs might have changed
    \global\let\@defaultsubs\@tempsubs
    % define a temporary macro for \ifx
    \escapechar\m@ne
    \edef\@tempa{\string\sb}%
    % get the computed current series
    % see \define@newfont in latex.ltx
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
       \split@name\expandafter\string\font@name\@nil
    % compare the current series with sb
    \ifx\f@series\@tempa
      \aftergroup\@tempswatrue
    \fi
  }%
  \if@tempswa
    % sb exists
    \fontseries{sb}\selectfont
  \else
    \bfseries
  \fi
}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsb}{\sbseries}
\makeatother  

\begin{document}

abc

\textsb{abc}

\textbf{abc}

\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont
abc

\textsb{abc}

\textbf{abc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

egreg's answer is very good and probably better than what I'm about to suggest.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{libertine}% has sb
\makeatletter
\def\checkseries#1#2{%
  {\ifcsname\f@encoding/\f@family/#1/\f@shape\endcsname
    \fontseries{#1}%
  \else
    \fontseries{\bfdefault}%
  \fi
  \selectfont #2}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
rm \checkseries{sb}{sb?} \textbf{bf}
\par\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont
rm \checkseries{sb}{sb?} \textbf{bf}
\end{document}
```

In fact, the main reason for me answering here is to query whether this method is flawed. Sometimes simpler is better, but not always!

Comment: Well, I guess this is a better way indeed.

Comment: Both answers work well, honestly I'm not sure which one to accept..  I think egreg's because he answered earlier and used `textsb` but I prefer a mixed code :-)